# What exactly is the "oxygen reduction reaction"?

Tags: redox

Is it

$\ce{O2(g) + 4H^+(aq) + 4e^- \rightarrow 2H_2O(l)}$

and are there multiple types of ORR?

See here for context: http://www.nature.com/srep/2014/140122/srep03821/full/srep03821.html

Comment: Your reaction is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

According to your [cited paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/srep03821) the reaction they care most about is $$\ce{O2 + 4H+ + 4e- -> 2H2O}$$ as you are suggesting. This should also be the total reaction and the most interesting one for applications, e.g. in fuel cells.

There are various suggestions for the mechanistics of the Oxygen Reduction Reaction. A quite recent review was published by [Nagappan Ramaswamy and Sanjeev Mukerjee](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2012/491604). A very early general scheme can be found at [electronicstructure.wikidot.com](http://electronicstructure.wikidot.com/oxygen-reduction-reaction-on-platinum-using-dft), where they cited [Halina S. Wroblowa *et.al.*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0728%2876%2980250-1).

[image: wroblowa scheme]